# `ansible` ad-hoc command piped to `jq`

Tags: ansible

I would like to be able use `jq` to parse output from `ansible -m setup` command, but I cannot figure out how to get rid of the non-json output:

```
192.132.1.1 | SUCCESS =>  {"ansible_facts": ...
```

How can I suppress the `192.132.1.1 | SUCCESS =>`   output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not find any native flag in the ansible command to suppress the non-json part of the output. Here is the regex based removal of undesired string:

```
ansible -m setup localhost | sed -r '1s/^.*?=> //g'
```

Above command would remove the strings like below from the output and the remaining would be a valid JSON.

```
localhost | SUCCESS => {
```

or

```
localhost | FAILED! =>
```

Eg: Test should `jq` is happy with the resulted output:

```
ansible -m setup localhost  |sed -r '1s/^.*?=> //g'|jq -e . &>/dev/null; echo $?
0
```

Comment: I had come up with basically the same solution.  I was just hoping there were some formatting option I could pass to ansible to suppress that noise.